# derivative of a distribution in differential geometry formalism

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, markov-chains

I'm trying to understand this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.3489) on Adiabatic Monte Carlo I came across. However it uses some notions that are unfamiliar to me.
In particular, he refers to a distribution $\pi$ and a base measure $\pi_B$ and then writes
$$
\pi = \frac{d\pi}{d\pi_B} \pi_B
$$
My hold on measure theory is rather shaky, so I'm thrown off by the differential geometry formalism being thrown around, but is this the same as a probability measure $d\pi$ having a density $f[x]$ with respect to another measure $d\lambda$ such that
$$
d\pi[U] = \int_Uf[x]d\lambda[x]
$$ ?

And if not, what is this called and where can I get some proper definitions to build my understanding off of ?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Essentially it is the same thing as $\pi$ having density $f(x)$ with respect to $\pi_B$. In this context, $d\pi/d\pi_B$ is called the "Radon-Nikodym derivative" of $\pi$ with respect to $\pi_B$. It isn't really a differential geometry concept, strictly speaking, even though the differential notation is used. It is properly a measure theory/probability concept. A graduate real analysis book like "papa rudin" or Folland's book covers this in more detail. There is also a good explanation of this in Durrett's *Probability, Theory and Examples* which is made free by the author online.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I've seen the term Radon-Nikodym derivative thrown around but have been relying more on my own intuition when it comes to measures. I'll have to check out one of the books you mention.